# Windows 8.1/Galaxy S2 not recognised

Tags: android, windows

This is a complete nightmare. All I'm trying to do is get my Win 8.1 to recognize my Galaxy S2, so I don't have to run the android emulator, but can run my apps straight from android studio on my phone.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Installed "Samsung USB Drivers" (twice)
2. Installed Samsung KIAS
3. Tried 3 different cables on 3 different ports on my laptop. Two of the cables came with my Samsung Note. The cables work fine with other phones.
4. Typed '#7...#' code and an 'Modem/USB' interface came up, I selected USB.
5. Enabled 'USB Debugging' on the phone.

Restarted my comp countless times, still nothing..

What I noticed is weird:

1. Phone doesn't even show up under 'Other Devices' on the device manager or anywhere else.
2. When I enable 'USB Mass Storage' on the phone, nothing happens.

Any other suggestions? **is there any other way I can run my apps on the phone while coding? is it possible to run it through blutooth?**

My phone specs:
SAMSUNG-SGH-I727
Android: 4.0.4

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, use Linux and format windows 8.1. I was joking :) You can install a virtual machine with Linux and work with it.

Comment: I gather you got the Samsung SGH-I727 USB drivers from [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I727), right?

Comment: Yup, and still phone is not recognized..